# Forking out matches from a string

Tags: c++, regex, qt

How to get all matches from a string using regex?
I have a string:

```
".+(.cpp$|.cxx$|.d$|.h$|.hpp$)"
```

and I would like to get only the cpp cxx d h and hpp parts.
EDIT:
So basically I would like to construct regex which would match any string of characters starting with dot and ending with $.
I've tried the pattern:  `"\\.[^$+]+"` which is supposed to match dot and everything else except $ and plus one or more times but this gets just the first .cpp part and I need all of them

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Are you asking how to use regexes in C++, or are you asking which regex matches your pattern? Those should be two separate questions.

Comment: #Kerrek SB I'm asking how to form a regex that would get those extensions from string and those extensions only. It is tagged c++ because when I didn't tagged questions concerning regex with language people were asking what language I'm using.

Comment: @user336635: Then how do you use the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention Qt in your question, here is how you would do it using `QRegExp`:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  QString target(".+(.cpp$|.cxx$|.d$|.h$|.hpp$)");
  QRegExp pattern("\\.(\\w+)\\$");

  QStringList matches;
  int pos = 0;
  while ((pos = pattern.indexIn(target, pos)) != -1) {
    matches << pattern.cap(1);
    pos += pattern.matchedLength();
  }

  qDebug() << matches;  // "cpp", "cxx", "d", "h", "hpp"
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: #Dave Mateer thanks, was just about to do the same. Thanks. One note only, I thought that there may be a regex option to fork those matches without looping.

Answer (score 0):

There's no generic solution as it really depends on how your regex implementation works and how it can be called - and considering there's no standard one for C++ (yet), you should mention which one you're using.

First of all you have to escape `.`, if it's meant to match a `.` and not just "any character". Also, I'd change the regex: `"\.(d|[ch](?:pp|xx)?)$"`. This way you keep the dot as well as the line ending outside your match.

For the actual call (which will depend on your implementation) you'll have to use some kind of `MATCH_ALL` or `GLOBAL_MATCH` flag or simply loop over your input string, always starting after the previous match. Considering the line ending, you might simply use it once per input line (as I don't know your input data).

Answer (score 0):

Find the location of the last "." and test the remaining string against all the suffixes you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the elements between the punctuation marks, you can use them as separator to split the string with `QStringList::split`:

```
QString target = ".+(.cpp$|.cxx$|.d$|.h$|.hpp$)";
QStringList extensions = target.split(QRegExp("\\W+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);

qDebug() << extensions; // ("cpp", "cxx", "d", "h", "hpp")
```